# xinput script for device with 2 entries

Tags: bash, scripts, mouse, xinput

I have an Elecom trackball mouse that I wish to swap left and right mouse buttons.  Using `xinput | grep "ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse"`I get the following output:

```
⎜   ↳ ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I created a script to swap the left and right mouse buttons that runs at boot:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ELECOM TrackBall Mouse
# swap middle and right buttons xinput --set-button-map 10 3 2 1
```

The problem with the script is that every time you restart the computer, the trackball id number changes, so sometimes the script works and sometimes it doesn't.  I can't key the script to the name of the device, because there are two device entries.  I need a way to key to the name of the device AND the slave pointer designation, but have no idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to extract the id directly in the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# get current id from xinput
id=$(xinput | sed -nE 's/.*ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse.*id=([0-9]+).*pointer.*/\1/p')
# swap middle and right buttons
xinput --set-button-map $id 3 2 1
```

The `sed` command searches `xinput`’s output for the matching line, replaces it with the id number and `p`rints only (`-n`) this line, i.e. just the number. This id is saved as variable `$id` which is then simply used in the `xinput` command. One could even leave out the variable and just write

```bsh
xinput --set-button-map $(xinput | sed …) 3 2 1
```

but that’s not very clear – in a script, I prefer the variable with an explanatory comment.

---

You could also `grep` two times to extract the correct id:

```bsh
xinput | grep pointer | grep -oP "ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse *id=\K[0-9]+"
```

The first `grep` excludes every line not containing “pointer”, the second one prints just the id in the line containing “ELECOM ELECOM TrackBall Mouse” using [PCRE black magic](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).

Comment: You’re welcome! If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.